# pyinstaller: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used PyInstaller 3.6 to package a PyQt5 program, and the packaging process indicated an error:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cffi/pycache/_cffi_ext.c:269:10: fatal error:
 'zmq.h' file not found

[image]

But still can generate executable file: exam.app, double-click the file, it cannot be opened, it cannot be opened with the terminal, and an error is reported: LSOpenURLsWithRole () failed with error -10810 for the file / Users / wenlong / GitHub / exam_demo / dist  /exam.app.

[image]

Tried both versions of PyInstaller 3.6 / 3.5, the results are the same.
 Environment: Python 3.7.6
 macOS 10.13.6

Excuse me, how can this problem be solved?

Comment: I have solved the first problem by:
"brew install zeromq"
But the second problem remains unresolved.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Did you fix it? I have same issue.